# How can I get all accounts from Metamask that connected to my website?

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am using web3 and Metamask in chrome. I'd like to get all accounts connected to my website with below code:

```
ethereum.request({
      method: 'eth_accounts',
    });
```

I have created two accounts in Metamask and connected both of them to this website. However, the above code only return the current selected accounts. Is there a way to get all connects from the wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to privacy reasons, Metamask currently cannot return all the connected accounts.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356216/metamask-multiple-getting-all-connected-accounts

Answer (score 1):

It seems [wallet_getPermissions](https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/reference/rpc-api/#wallet_requestpermissions) does that:

```
ethereum
   .request({method: 'wallet_getPermissions'})
   .then(res => {
      console.log('Connected accounts:', res[0]?.caveats?.[0]?.value);
   })
   .catch(err => {
     console.log('Error getting permissions:', err);
   });
```

I'm not sure how reliable this is but it does return array of connected accounts.

Comment: From @Dimitry Yudakov (thanks), I confirm this is possible to get all accounts connected to it by using the [wallet_getPermissions](https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/reference/rpc-api/#wallet_getpermissions). Here is a quick [video](https://www.loom.com/share/544538a30df043a69ae0c7a19460f121) or picture > [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ohZO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ohZO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can since the "connection" of metamask to your website is kept on the metamask side, not the website side.

But you can have your backend look at the address and check in the database if that address is a new user, and if yes then you just save that address into your DB.